# Is there solution i'm facing E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:

Tags: java, android, xml

```
2022-09-05 22:15:46.726 5385-5385/com.example.recyclerview_practice_4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.recyclerview_practice_4, PID: 5385
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.recyclerview_practice_4.Adapter.RecyclerViewCustomAdapter.getItemCount(RecyclerViewCustomAdapter.java:45)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4044)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3849)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

2022-09-05 22:20:54.963 5452-5452/com.example.recyclerview_practice_4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.recyclerview_practice_4, PID: 5452
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
at com.example.recyclerview_practice_4.Adapter.RecyclerViewCustomAdapter.getItemCount(RecyclerViewCustomAdapter.java:45)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4044)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3849)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2022-09-05 22:28:22.360 5544-5544/com.example.recyclerview_practice_4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.recyclerview_practice_4, PID: 5544
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
at com.example.recyclerview_practice_4.Adapter.RecyclerViewCustomAdapter.getItemCount(RecyclerViewCustomAdapter.java:45)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:4044)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3849)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

**here i'm providing my java code and yes i'm a beginner so pls i'm sorry for any silly work**
**Some of the things which i want to share is that**
**1)i've checked my api key**
**2)and for some reason for small Json data it's working but for little big data like news
it's not**
**3)i've tried a lot,find out my issue but i was unable to rectify it**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONArray article_array = response.getJSONArray("articles");
                for (int i = 0; i < article_array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = article_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    News news = new News(object.getString("author"), object.getString("title"),
                            object.getString("description"), object.getString("url"),
                            object.getString("urlToImage"), object.getString("publishedAt"));
                    newsArrayList.add(news);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("fine", "Something Wrong" + error);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something Wrong " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
    RecyclerViewCustomAdapter recyclerViewCustomAdapter = new RecyclerViewCustomAdapter(this, newsArrayList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewCustomAdapter);

}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="335dp"
        android:id="@+id/card"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#BEDFFF"
        android:backgroundTint="#BEDBF8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/constraint_1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_cardview_activity_1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/constraint_1"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/constraint_1"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/constraint_1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/newsimage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/newsheadline"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text=""
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/newsauthor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="author"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.recyclerview_practice_4.Adapter.RecyclerViewCustomAdapter.getItemCount(RecyclerViewCustomAdapter.java:45)
```

<strike>seems like your JSON does not contain an array called "articles", so you get a null pointer when attempting to ask for the `.length()` of a null object.</strike>

Sorry that's not your problem.

The problem is your `RecyclerViewCustomAdapter` but you have not shared the code for that class. Inside that class you call `.size()` on a null object.

Comment: I rechecked my JSON sir, It do containes json array ("articles"). So to help you to understand my problem more effectively i'm sharing you my json link,You can check it out 
[link](https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=e22bc225b786446cb8dc5c792202df40)